# "a long time"...why is it countable?

Tags: grammar

I've gone through many threads here trying to find the answer, but to no avail.

Cambridge dictionary states: *We use **time** to refer to what is measured in seconds, minutes, hours and years as a whole. In this sense it is **uncountable**:*

Ex: *Children nowadays spend more **time** watching TV than playing.* (spent many **hours**)

So my questions is, how is the meaning in the sentence above different from, say, *"I've spent a long time doing that"?* (spent many **hours**) Can't we say "much time" in that sentence?. Which would mean the same, but then it'd be **uncountable**.

I just can't understand why **"time"** considered to be **"countable"** in a sentence like that.

"I've been there many times" = on many occasions. Here, it's clearly countable. So it is in *"I've played football for a long time"*, but we can't really say "I've played football for a long occasion", can we?
Hopefully I'm not asking something stupid..

Comment: A long time is a continuous period; much time need not be.

Comment: Because in *a long time*, *time* is not being used in the same uncountable sense as. The only reason we don't say *for a long occasion* is that it's arbitrarily unidiomatic in that context, not because it's an noncountable noun.

Answer (score -1):

*When we talk about the amount of time (number of hours/days etc.) required to complete something, time is usually uncountable.*

But *in expressions like **a long time** or **a short time**, the word time is used as a countable noun.*

https://www.englishgrammar.org/time-countable-uncountable-noun/

We can use **such a/an** with a singular countable noun : 
*"We had such a good time together".*

*On occasion, on three occasions, on several occasions, on the occasion of something, for the occasion, for many occasions* etc. are idiomatic; but **"for a long occasion" is unidiomatic.**